# How to get all destinations composed by NavHostController grouped by NavigationBarItem?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

### Problem

I am using `NavHostController` along with `NavigationBarItems`. These `NavigationBarItem` can all route to a nested view. For some reason, I want to see if a particular nested view is already composed and in which `NavigationBarItem` this is composed.

### What I want

I want to have some sort of method in which I can see a breakdown of all destinations with arguments grouped by `NavigationBarItem`. This way, I can see if a screen is already open in memory in some `NavigationBarItem`.

### Why I want this

I am showing notification to users. When a user presses a notification, I want to route the user to the correct screen. I don't want to create a screen if that screen is already composed. Then, I want to just show the already created screen.

### Code

I added code in which I added 2 `NavigationBarItem`s and 1 nested view. Let's say that if you press on tab b and than open the nested view, I am hoping I can call a method which gives me this information:

`class Destination(val route: String, val vararg arguments: String)`

```
[Tab A: List<>] // There is a no nested view open
[Tab B: List<Destination("nested", "uuid-here")>]
```

The code:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val items = listOf(
        Triple("a", Icons.Default.Person, Icons.Filled.Person),
        Triple("b", Icons.Default.Notifications, Icons.Filled.Notifications),
    )
    var selectedTab = items[0]
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    selectedTab = item

                    val isSelected = index == items.indexOf(selectedTab)

                    NavigationBarItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                if (isSelected) item.second else item.third,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(text = item.first) },
                        selected = isSelected,
                        onClick = {
                            navHostController.navigate(item.first) {
                                popUpTo(navHostController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }

                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navHostController,
            startDestination = items[0].first,
            Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            composable(items[0].first) {
                Column {
                    Text("first")
                    Button(onClick = {
                        navHostController.navigate(
                            "nested/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                        )
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Go to nested")
                    }
                }
            }
            composable(items[1].first) {
                Column {
                    Text("Second")
                    Button(onClick = {
                        navHostController.navigate(
                            "nested/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                        )
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Go to nested")
                    }
                }
            }
            composable("nested/{id}") {
                Text("nested")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially leverage **NavBackStackEntry** to inspect the current and previous destinations in your **NavController**.

*Here's a conceptual approach:*

First, create a **MutableState** that holds a **Map** of the **NavigationBarItem** and the composed destinations:

```
val navMap = remember { mutableStateOf<Map<NavigationBarItem, List<Destination>>>(emptyMap()) }
```

Then, add an **OnDestinationChangedListener** that updates this map whenever navigation occurs:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
val currentScreen = Destination(destination.route, arguments?.toList())
// Add 'currentScreen' to the corresponding 'NavigationBarItem' in the map. 
}
```

Please note that this is a simplified idea and the actual implementation could be more complex. It might need to account for the lifecycle of screens as they get composed and discarded, as well as define what constitutes a unique **NavigationBarItem**.